# Security Updates make server software not work anymore

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, updates, notification

How often happens that automatic security updates make some standard webserver daemons (like LAMP or SSH or FTP or TOMCAT) not work properly anymore.

I run a basic webserver with Ubuntu 16.4 LTS on it. automatic security updates are enabled. And there is LAMP, SSH, FTP , TOMCAT running on it.
Do the automatic Security updates update apache , tomcat and myql etc... too?

I have multiple (vHost) Wordpress-sites running on LAMP.
**Is there a chance that the security updates make my wordpress sites or tomcat applications not work properly anymore?**

Is it worth to get automatic email notifications about automatic installed security updates so i can check when apache is updated that wordpress or something else is still running properly?

Or are Security Updates to 99% fine and i shouldn't worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do the automatic Security updates update apache , tomcat and myql etc... too?

If you installed those daemons from the Ubuntu package system (with `apt` on the command line, a GUI like the Software Center etc.), there will be updates for them as well (as long as the respective Ubuntu version gets updates). It may take a day or two longer, because after the project (for example the Apache HTTPd people) released a new version, the updated Ubuntu packages need to be built and tested.

If you installed the daemons from some other source, updates (security or otherwise) are up to you.

> Is there a chance that the security updates make my wordpress sites or tomcat applications not work properly anymore?

In German, we have the saying "Man hat schon Pferde vor der Apotheke kotzen sehen", which translates to about "People have seen horses barf in front of the drug store". The gist of it is, even the most unusual things *can* still happen. So yes, there *is* a chance that a security update interferes with your applications. But I'd reckon that chance is very small. The risk could be increased by several factors

- Maybe you deviated from Ubuntus standards and defaults in your setup
- Maybe you're running older applications that are no longer maintained
- Maybe you're running applications that are less common. If, say, a MySQL security updates breaks WordPress, there are likely a whole bunch of people looking into it, and fast. Smaller projects may be less agile to react to problems. With WordPress (or Drupal, for example), I'd take plugins, modules etc. into account, as well.

> Is it worth to get automatic email notifications about automatic installed security updates so i can check when apache is updated that wordpress or something else is still running properly?

I'd reckon the notifications worth my time in any case, if only to let me rest easy at night.

> Or are Security Updates to 99% fine and i shouldn't worry.

Security updates *are* to 99% fine, but it doesn't do harm to throw a glance at the updated machine, just in case.